# What happens when a gate moves onto a vortex?

Tags: arkham-horror

If a moving gate (from the Lurker at the Threshold expansion) would move into a vortex in Dunwich, what happens? My best guess is that, since the rules say it moves as a normal monster, it moves into the vortex, and, like a monster, adds a horror token to the track.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Moving gates cannot move onto Vortexes.**

From a [post on Fantasy Flight's forum](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_foros_discusion.asp?efid=5&efcid=1&efidt=444686):

> Gates can't enter Vortexes. In this situation, the vortex is treated like an open gate, and gates can't move onto gates.
>
> If a gate has to move into a vortex, it just stays in place instead.

I do not believe that the answerer, Tibs, is an official representative of Fantasy Flight.  However, he has nearly 4000 posts in their Arkham Horror forums and seems to have a very good grasp upon the rules.